# What's the best way to perform CRUD with ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

By default, ASP.NET MVC's implementation of `Identity` for authentication does not support full `CRUD` operations for it's users.

I know it already `has`:

> Register, Login, Manage, and Change Password

But the problem is that `doesn't have`:

> Account Update or Edit, Select User Role, and Delete User

I think that `Identity` is still **incomplete** in a way that there is no concise documentation which causes me to have a very ugly looking learning curve. Or if there's a better way and place to learn it, **can you guide me there?** Thank you very much!

Comment: Asp.Net Identity has a `UserManager` that has methods to do all these operations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613059%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a quick example of some of the methods that are availalbe.

> Users

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Email);
await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
```

> Roles

```
ApplicationDbContext context;
context = new ApplicationDbContext();

// Create Role
context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
{
    Name = RoleName
});
context.SaveChanges();

// Delete Role
var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals("Admin", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
context.Roles.Remove(thisRole);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope this helps, Identity is great!!