# How to create CRUD for table AspNetUsers in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I create a CRUD for table AspNetUsers, creating a MVC controller 5 with views using Entity Framework

This is the structure of the table AspNetUsers

[image]

This is the IdentityModels

[image]

Comment: You can use the UserManager class to manage the AspNetUsers table. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30525309/1504480)

Comment: @AbregoW If my answer fixed your problem. Please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

You can access this from the `DbContext` itself using `DbContext.Users` or you can do this by the `UserManager`. The `DbContext` should be used for relations and updating all non-essential properties in the `ApplicationUser` model. For creating a user, logging in, logging out, adding two-step authentication, etc you should use the `UserManager`. The best example for the use of the UserManager is to create a new asp.net 5 project. It shows exactly what it can do.